# Unable to SSO login Jenkins SAML 2.0 ADFS integration

Tags: authentication, jenkins, saml-2.0, adfs

We are able to login to Jenkins using SSO from the past one year without any issues.

Today, however the SSO failed for the entire team and no one can login anymore.

After providing the SSO AD credentials we are thrown to the SAMLLougout page.

[image]

Upon investigation the ADFS team informed that one of the certificates from Jenkins  has expired. The sanpshot of the expired certificate as shared by the ADFS team for our Jenkins is below:

[image]

[image]

We have never created this certificate nor do we have any idea about it. Is this something that comes default with the SAML plugin or the Jenkins product? Please let me know.

Now, that we are not able to login to Jenkins how do we go about fixing the issue and updating the certificate ?

I'm using the latest version of the standalone Jenkins war.

Any help guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove certificates from JENKINS_HOME and restart jenkins service. Jenkins will generate new certificates:

- Delete the following file from JENKINS_HOME: saml-jenkins-keystore.jks saml-jenkins-keystore.xml jenkins.cer.
- Restart Jenkins.
- Access JENKINS via web inteface. This will generate new saml-jenkins-keystore.jks saml-jenkins-keystore.xml
- Generate jenkins.cer using the new jks `keytool -export -alias saml-generated-keypair -keystore saml-jenkins-keystore.jks -rfc -file jenkins.cer`
- Give this new jenkins.cer to ADFS Team which they will import and this will resolve the issue.

You can move these files to /home/ folder to restore them if everything will go wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I found the expired cert here -> `JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.cer` I moved it outside the `JENKINS_HOME` along with `JENKINS_HOME/saml-jenkins-keystore.jks JENKINS_HOME/saml-jenkins-keystore.xml` and all files under `JENKINS_HOME/secrets` were moved too. Restarted jenkins but sadly it still does not work and i get the samlLogut page :( @Dmitriy Tarasevich

Comment: If we delete JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.cer it does not recreate it despite restarts. Although I'm not an expert i tried creating a new jenkins.cer using this command -> openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -out jenkins.cer -days 365 -subj '/CN=SAML-jenkins' and copying the new created jenkins.cer to JENKINS_HOME/jenkins.cer it too did not work Note: I did not copy the key.pem generated from the above command as I'm not sure if and with what name should it be copied under `JENKINS_HOME` :(

Comment: Please, list all files from JENKINS_HOME. I will take a look.

Comment: I found the solution. Will share here later today so you could update the answer Thanks @Dmitriy Tarasevich

Comment: Solution: 1. Delete the following file from `JENKINS_HOME` `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks saml-jenkins-keystore.xml jenkins.cer`. 2. Restart Jenkins. 3. Now, access JENKINS Admin console from browser. This will generate new `saml-jenkins-keystore.jks saml-jenkins-keystore.xml` 4. Generate jenkins.cer using the new jks `keytool -export -alias saml-generated-keypair -keystore saml-jenkins-keystore.jks -rfc -file jenkins.cer`. 5. Give this new jenkins.cer to ADFS Team which they will import and this will resolve the issue. @Dmitriy Tarasevich kindly update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I feel let down that this is not documented by Jenkins nor discussed anywhere when this can be a showstopper for large scale organizations depending on Jenkins for most of their operations :(

Comment: Nice. I forgot the files' names to be deleted)